# Xcode 5 and Images

Tags: ios, xcode, image

I have an app that uses button images that are being changed as the user interacts with the button.

I just converted my app to iOS7 in Xcode 5, but now my button images are not showing any more.  All I see is a bright blue square where the button should be.

When I change the tint from blue to clear, the buttons show, but the button does not change when I push it.

The images are still in my supported files folder and should be properly used by Xcode...

Does anyone have a similar issue? Can this be fixed easily?

Answer (score 3):

There is a new button type called UIButtonTypeSystem with iOS 7.

On your .xib file, change the button type to Custom.

[image]